# Is there a shortcut to open layout files (.xml) in android studio?

Tags: android

I can use command + o to search for java class files.
but how to find .xml files?

Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply press `Command + Shift + O` then type in `.xml`

Comment: You saved me! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

select the .xlm in java class and press clrt + shift + n..... it will open the .xlm :p

Answer (score 2):

I still better option is provided by Android studio but may be no have look into it .I am providing screenshots to how you just specify files types in filer to **speed up the searching process and get exactly the same files you require**.

**Step .1** Specify types of the files you require.Deselect the file types you don't want .I always keep **Java and xml** only in android  project.

[image]

**Step-2.** Start Searching..

[image]

**Step-3** : Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 2):

Windows/Linux press `Control + Shift + N`

Mac press `Command + Shift + O`